# Cycle through all points of an image C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a bitmap object, which is 40px by 40px. I would like to be able to loop through every single pixel in the image.

```
E.g. 1,1
1,2
1,3
...
2,1
2,4
...
39,1
39,2
and so on
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for best way or any way?

Comment: @L.B Any way really, but an efficient one as well

Comment: This is seriously something you could Google, but I'll make it easier for you: `Bitmap.LockData` for efficient x,y iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps. Note that there are both newer (System.Windows.Media) `Bitmap` and older (System.Drawing) `BitmapImage` classes if I'm not mistaken, and these may behave slightly differently.

```
Bitmap bmp = ...  // Get bitmap
for(int x=0; x<bmp.PixelWidth; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y<bmp.PixelHeight; y++)
    {
        Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x,y);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Color at ({0},{1}) is {2}", x, y, c));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using GetPixel for each pixel separately is REALLY slow. The method should only be used if you want a single pixel at the time.

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to do this more efficiently. This is just an the simplest (and slowest) way. See comment on question: -"Any way really".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method which uses LockBits.  It uses an unsafe code block, however:

```
private void processPixels()
{
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\folder\SomeFileName.png", FileMode.Open))
    {
        bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(fs);
    }

    BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

    for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width; j++)
        {
            Color c = getPixel(bmd, j, i);

            //Do something with pixel here
        }
    }

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);
}

private Color getPixel(BitmapData bmd, int x, int y)
{
    Color result;

    unsafe
    {
        byte* pixel1 = (byte*)bmd.Scan0 + (y * bmd.Stride) + (x * 3);
        byte* pixel2 = (byte*)bmd.Scan0 + (y * bmd.Stride) + ((x * 3) + 1);
        byte* pixel3 = (byte*)bmd.Scan0 + (y * bmd.Stride) + ((x * 3) + 2);

        result = Color.FromArgb(*pixel3, *pixel2, *pixel1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This also assumes that the image is 24 bit color, RGB. It will fail if the image has any other format.

Comment: @JimMischel - Right, and I'm not sure what would happen if the image contains any alpha information, as the getPixel method doesn't take that into account either.